# Single File Upload Check in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file, upload

Following code transfer file successfully, but does not print in lable that it has been transferred. Although other checks were shown perfectly. Is there any logical eror in it?

```
        if (txtFile1.HasFile)
        {
        var folderfile1 = Server.MapPath("~/files/Operations_Support/IMSI");
        string flFile1 = txtFile1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string saveflFile1 = folderfile1 + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(flFile1);

        FileInfo Finfo = new FileInfo(txtFile1.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (Finfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".txt")
        {
            if (txtFile1.PostedFile.ContentLength < 1024)
            {
                //if (!File.Exists(folderfile1))
                if (Directory.GetFiles(folderfile1).Length == 0)
                {
                    txtFile1.SaveAs(saveflFile1);
                    //lbFile1.Visible = true;
                    lbFile1.Text = "Upload status: IMSI file transfered successfully";
                }

                else
                {
                    lbFile1.Text = "Upload status: Please wait until the previous file is processed";
                }

            }
            else
                lbFile1.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 1 kb!";
        }
        else
            lbFile1.Text = "Upload status: Only Text files are accepted!";
    }
    else
    {
        lbFile1.Visible = true;
        lbFile1.Text = "Upload status: Please select file";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `File.Exists` like this:

```
var folderfile4 = Server.MapPath("~/files/Path");
string saveflFile4 = folderfile4 + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(flFile4);
if(!File.Exists(saveflFile4))
    txtFile4.SaveAs(saveflFile4);
else
    txtError.Text = "File exists";
```

`Server.MapPath` returns a physical path on the server, so you can use `File.Exists` to check if the file is present or not.

Comment: I see you implemented `File.Exists`, what problem do you get now? It always returns true?

Comment: exactly, it is transferring file each time if the destination folder have a file. I just want to transfer file if the destination folder is empty only.

Comment: You are getting the filename from the file that was uploaded. So `File.Exists` will return true only if you upload the same file again. Use a fixed file name on the server if you want to allow only one file at a time. `string saveflFile4 = Server.MapPath("~/files/Path/processingFile.dat");`

Comment: my requirement will change each time when file is uploaded regarding its name. Is there not any mehtod where i can put a check that file will transfer only if the destination folder is empty, kindly assist?

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(folderfile4).Length == 0` Will check if the dir is empty.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. Are you getting an exception saving the file?

Answer (score 0):

use the File.Exists method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

Comment: Hi, I am using     var folderfile4 = Server.MapPath("~/files/Path");     its not a local directory. its server directory path...

Comment: it will still work as nunespascal said however you could have some permission issues